# ROR + Generate Text Report using XML file

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, report

In Rails 3.1, I want to generate a text report for Patient Records using xml file but I am not getting the way to implement this.

Please suggest the way through which report can be generated using XML file.

Comment: Do you want to generate text report from XML file?

Comment: Mr Soundar, Actually I am not getting the concept of retriving input from XML file to generate a report. Report may be pdf, doc format.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with 'crystal-reports'?